# How to create a new instance of a model in sailjs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I want to create a not persisted new instance from a model, populate some attributes and send it back as a JSON response from a controller action. In `rails` it's pretty simple to get a new instance of a model with `Model.new`, but how can I do that with `waterline` or `sails.js`?

If you are familiar with rails:

- `Model.new ->` Creates a new instance of a model. **How can I do this in Sails.JS?**
- `Model.create ->` Creates a new instance of a model, which is (already) persisted.

I've already checked the documentation, but I couldn't find anything about this.

Comment: At the time, when I was asking this, there was no way to do this. Maybe now it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, this isn't something that's currently supported by Waterline. Luckily, the OSS community is here to help.

Check this little NPM package out, as it looks like it will take care of exactly what you need.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-model-new